# WordPress "Notice: Undefined index: host" after initial setup running locally on linux

Tags: php, linux, wordpress

I'm trying to set up WordPress on my laptop running Kali Linux. Everything works until I install WordPress and the theme I am using. I'm trying to use roots sage on bedrock. But after I get through the installation process I get a notice in the admin:

```
Notice: Undefined index: host in /var/www/html/site/web/wp/wp-includes/theme.php on line 2937
Notice: Undefined index: host in /var/www/html/site/web/wp/wp-includes/theme.php on line 2937
Notice: Undefined index: host in /var/www/html/site/web/wp/wp-includes/theme.php on line 2999
Notice: Undefined index: host in /var/www/html/site/web/wp/wp-includes/theme.php on line 2999
```

And in the frontend:

```
Notice: Undefined index: host in /var/www/html/site/web/wp/wp-includes/theme.php on line 2999
Notice: Undefined index: host in /var/www/html/site/web/wp/wp-includes/theme.php on line 2999
```

Can anyone explain why I'm getting these notices? I must have missed something but I've gone through the instructions several times and I'm out of ideas. Thanks

Comment: This is probably a wordpress bug. Similar report there: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/undefined-host-in-themephp/ - Try out the fix they suggest (changing the wp-config.php to contain your home URL)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can define WP_HOME & WP_SITEURL in wp-config.php

```
define('WP_HOME','http://localhost/project_folder_name');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://localhost/project_folder_name');
```

Answer (score 8):

This can also be caused by an error with the `siteurl` and `home` options in `wp_options` table.

Make sure the url's have a host as well, `http://example.com` not just `example.com`.

Answer (score 0):

I just now came across this and for me, switching back from PHP 8.x.x to PHP 7.x.x resolved the issue.